# Loss matrix in R's package rpart

Tags: r, rpart

Trying to understand how the loss-parameter works in the rpart package in R

Looking at this example: https://www.listendata.com/2015/04/ways-to-correct-class-imbalances.html
it tells me that the cost matrix should be entered with the highest misclassification cost in the cell that is the least desired prediction.

This makes sense to me, as we'd like the classifier to predict classes that are cheap to misclassify. However, when I try to run a simple tree with an extreme cost matrix, I see the opposite results of what I expect.

df is the titanic dataset

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

df <- df[, c("Survived", "Pclass", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare", "Embarked")]


loss_matr <- matrix(c(0, 1000000000000000000000, 1, 0), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

print(loss_matr)

fit <- rpart(Survived ~ ., data = df, method = "class", parms = list(loss = loss_matr))
rpart.plot(fit, fallen.leaves = FALSE, type = 1)

pred <- predict(fit, type = "class")
confusionMatrix(pred, df$Survived)
```

Looking at the confusion matrix, I see that the classifier hasn't predicted the class 1 at all, when in fact I expected class 0 to not be predicted, i.e. in my binary-class case, False-Negatives would be the most unwelcome outcome.

Have I misunderstood the concept of the loss-matrix?

EDIT:
The structure of the matrix in the blog-post is opposite to what I have, which is why I have the order as above. Here is a similar structure to what I have:
http://datamining.togaware.com/survivor/Loss_Matrix.html

*"An example is the string of numbers 0,10,1,0, which might be interpreted as saying that an actual 1, predicted as 0 (i.e., a false negative) is 10 times more unwelcome that a false positive!"*

How can I know in which order the rpart classifier (or any other) sets my classes?

Thx

Comment: where does the titanic data set come from?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/karlkonz/exploring-the-titanic-dataset-with-r/data

Answer (score 2):

The blog post that you site says that the layout for the cost matrix is

```
TP   FP
FN   TN
```

But your cost matrix is:

```
loss_matr
     [,1]  [,2]
[1,]    0 1e+21
[2,]    1 0e+00
```

that is, you have assigned a high cost to False Positives,
not to False Negatives. You need

```
loss_matr <- matrix(c(0, 1000000000000000000000, 1, 0), nrow = 2)
```

Comment: yes, the cost-matrix in the blog-post has the opposite structure, and I've adjusted the costs accordingly. The way you have stated my cost-matrix to be is what I have, i.e. 

loss_matr <- matrix(c(0, 1000000000000000000000, 1, 0), nrow = 2)

Here is how my matrix structure looks:
http://datamining.togaware.com/survivor/Loss_Matrix.html

and if we look at this row:
"An example is the string of numbers 0,10,1,0, which might be interpreted as saying that an actual 1, predicted as 0 (i.e., a false negative) is 10 times more unwelcome that a false positive!"

class 0 should be penalized

Comment: What you have stated works if my classifier structures the classes in that order, but how can I know which class comes first for the classifier?
Thx

Comment: You are right. The togaware site says the opposite of what it says at ListenData. The documentation does not seem to offer much help. Beyond just trying both ways to see what works, I do not know how to know which structure to use.

Comment: [Yet another site](http://www.learnbymarketing.com/tutorials/rpart-decision-trees-in-r/) has what sounds like the right information. It depends on the order of the factors in your class variable.

Comment: Looking at the page you sent, I see this sentence:

"So for this given situation, it’s 5 times worse to generate a false positive than a false negative. This will have the effect of making Class1 predicted less frequently."

This doesn't make sense to me - it should be the direct opposite, i.e. Class2 should be predicted less frequently, no?